# How to execute next loop after specific time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In a foreach loop, how to execute the 2nd loop after 5 seconds of 1st loop, and then execute 3rd loop after 3 seconds of the 2nd loop?

1st loop

after 5 second

2nd loop

after 3 second

3rd loop

As I am doing Webbrowser automation in windows form,
there are numerous of link to be clicked automatically, after the link is clicked , it will automatically insert a text into a textbox and click on a submit button.
The process:

```
foreach (HtmlElement ahref in ahrefs)
{
    ahref.InvokeMember("click");

    Application.DoEvents();

    txtboxPrice.SetAttribute("value", "100");

    btnSubmit.InvokeMember("click");
 }
```

The problem of what i facing now is, the loop is too fast until the Webbrowser can't finish implement txtboxprice.setattribute and btnsubmit.invokemember, it already clicked on next loop's ahref.

Therefore, i need to  trigger time control in order to make sure txtboxprice.setattribute and btnsubmit.invokemember is implemented before proceed to next looping.

Comment: Why do you hardcode such number instead of some sort async approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System.Threading;

foreach(..) { } // your for or foreach or any code you want

Thread.Sleep(5000); // pause the current thread on x milliseconds

foreach(..) { }

Thread.Sleep(3000);

foreach(..) { }
```

Comment: I think he's asking how to pause during each iteration, so the Thread.Sleep would need to be placed inside the for each loop and parameterized some how.

Comment: @Nathan: Maybe. But the original question clearly asks how to pause between loops.

Comment: @abatischev, sorry for my bad english, nathan is right.
Besides, is thread.sleep will pause the application from working without doing anything?

Answer (score 2):

[Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method blocks the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Sleep for 2 seconds.");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
for(int i=0;i<number_of_times;i++)
{
....
    if(i == number_of_times - 1)
       Thread.Sleep(5000);//time in millsecond, namespace System.Threading
}

for(int i=0;i<number_of_times;i++)
{
....
    if(i == number_of_times - 1)
       Thread.Sleep(3000);
}

for(int i=0;i<number_of_times;i++)
{
....
}
```

But I wonder why you want to do such a thing.